# XML Array Element not assigning Attributes when deserialising (C#)

Tags: arrays, .net, xml, serialization, xml-attribute

I have a pre-existing XML structure which I want deserialised into C#.

The structure of the file is:

```
<SLOT_DEFINITION>
    <SLOT name="head" >
        <MESH model="head01.fbx" />
    </SLOT>
    <SLOT name="arm" >
        <MESH model="arm01.fbx" />
    </SLOT>
    <SLOT name="torso" >
        <MESH model="torso01.fbx" />
    </SLOT>
</SLOT_DEFINITION>
```

I've created some classes to represent this structure in C#:

```
[XmlRoot("SLOT_DEFINITION")]
public class SlotDefinition : List<Slot>
{

}

[XmlRoot("SLOT")]
[XmlType("SLOT")]
public class Slot : List<Mesh>
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("MESH")]
[XmlType("MESH")]
public class Mesh
{
    [XmlAttribute("model")]
    string ModelPath { get; set; }
}
```

But when I deserialise like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SlotDefinition));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xmlPath);
SlotDefinition slotDefinition = (SlotDefinition)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

<s>the elements of the `SlotDefinition`, and the `Slot` are populated, but the `Name` and `ModelPath` properties are not assigned their XMLAttribute values.</s>

**In fact**, the leaf-object (`Mesh`) *is* getting its `ModelPath` set. I just had to give it the `public` attribute. But after I do this, the `Slot` class still doesn't get its attribute.

I want to avoid defining my `SlotDefition` as a field on some other class, decorating it with `[XmlArrayItem]`, and deserialise that outer class. I also want to avoid writing custom deserialization logic since this seems like it should be a trivial structure.

Comment: You cannot use a inherited class.  The xml would need to have a 'type' attribute with the inherited class.  Try serializing test data using you current classes and see what the results look like.

Comment: I don't actually need to re-serialize any of this. But sure, I added an `[XmlType]` as well as `[XmlRoot]` to the `SlotDefinition` class. My issue still occurs.

Comment: You cannot use inherited classes.  The xml is missing the type attribute (not the classes).